# AEM Page manager return null for mapped page with Sling Mapping

Tags: aem, sling, wcm

I am using Sling Mapping (configurations are located under /etc/map) for mapping the resources , e.g. */content/path/en* should get page */content/path_real/en*.

When I try to get resource via ***resourceResolver.getResource("/content/path/en")*** it works correctly and return the resource under path */content/path_real/en*.

But when I try to get page via ***pageManger.getPage(""/content/path/en")*** it returns null.

Is there any way to configure pageManager so they also use sling mapping configuration from */etc/map* folder?

Comment: What do you try to achieve? 
The resourceResolver gives you a resource under given name. The pageManager will return you a page, only when the jcr:primaryType='cq:Page' otherwise it will be null. Sling Mapper has no impact on both as the Sling Mapper will only be called to generate links or resolving resources (inbound call).